# Can't preview the AppMaker

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

Since AppMaker has removed Drive Table, we have to use Cloud SQL instead. We managed to setup AppMaker with Cloud SQL and it seems to work just fine. However, I realized that I can’t preview the app, as I am getting this error:

[image]

Any suggestions on why is this happening?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes, I can launch the app after server team adds me to the GCP instance as one of the editors in which for me is not relevant because from there I already have access to the GCP. Suppose to be anyone across the organization should be able to link AppMaker to GCP when the appmaker-maestro@appspot.gserviceaccount.com role was added. I think Google team should looking forward into this matter.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using [Custom Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql) instance and you missed [the step](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql#create-a-new-google-cloud-sql-database-for-your-app) with adding `appmaker-maestro@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` account to `Cloud SQL Client` role.